# create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users, django-custom-user

I deleted `username` field because I wanted user to be able to login with their email address, so I have this in my `models.py` :

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE = ((1, 'HOD'), (2, 'Staff'), (3, 'Student'))
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=USER_TYPE, max_length=1)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


class Student(models.Model):
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)
    address = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    session_start_year = models.DateField(null=True)
    session_end_year = models.DateField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In my `views.py`, I tried :

```
user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email=email, password=password, user_type=3, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
```

But I got **create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'**
How can I fix this?

Comment: `create_user()` requires the first argument to be the username.  You are not passing this argument.

Comment: I deleted `username` from my model. I tried passing `username=None` but it says `The given username must be set`. How do I bypass this ? I do not want to keep `username` field at all. Email is okay for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write a [*manager for a custom user model* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model) to reimplement the `create_user` method.

You can thus implement a `CustomUserManager`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = CustomUser(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.password = make_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        assert extra_fields['is_staff']
        assert extra_fields['is_superuser']
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # …

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

and then you register this manager thus as the `objects` manager.

Comment: I just tried this but I got `name 'make_password' is not defined`. How do I fix this ?

Comment: @OwonubiJobSunday: you import it `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`

Comment: Can you explain what it is that we do here that make the username field optional, compared to how it is in the default mode, when username is required?

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem ! I'm trying to use code like you, but it appear the error : `TypeError: BaseManager.all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: @HuyNguyen: how are you using the manager...? Are you sure you added parenthesis at the end of `objects = CustomUserManager()`?